# how to reduce high memory usage with createReadStream when piped to response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, http

Below is the app.js I am using to play around with streams on a `Oracle Linux 7` docker container which is limited to 4gb of ram.

large-file is around 1gb textfile generated using `yes`

I have setup grafana with cadvisor to measure the container memory cache across the request lifecycle.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let stuff = fs.createReadStream('./large-file');
    stuff.pipe(res);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

node version: 14.18.1

Following is the graph after using `curl -o /dev/null localhost:3000`. The previous dip is due to clearing the page cache via `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

[image: Memory Usage]

I was under the impression using streams would reduce the memory footprint, but the graph seems to be showing otherwise with entire file being loaded to the buffer. Is there any way to avoid the same?